# The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match - Orchard 1.8.1

Tags: .net, azure, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I use @Html.AntiForgeryTokenOrchard() method to render the token. I get this error when submiting a form. The site is on Azure Web. When I use the original site name xxxx.azurewebsites.net the token works. Only, when I use the mapped domain name I get this error. The error is regardless of the browser, however if I force updating the site (CTRL+F5) and post the form, the token works. If I open a new incognito browser window it fails again for the new session.

I have the machine key configured in web.config.

Please, help me to get rid of this annoying bug. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Any caching involved?

Comment: The page has the required meta tags in order to avoid browser side caching, however I am not sure if any other caching takes place. How can I check that? Thx.

Comment: By looking at enabled features, and disabling it if it's enabled, and then trying again.

Comment: Thanks for the info. After really short testing it seems that this was the root of the problem. So, hopefully it should not appear again. However if I understand it correctly it means that I cannot use both anti forgery validation and the caching feature. Is it possible to configure this behavior at the page / action level? So I could decide whether I liked to exclude a certain page from the cache or I turned anti forgery validation off on a certain controller action? If it is possible to implement, where should I look for more info? Thank you

Comment: You just need to disable caching on those pages that must post with anti-forgery. You should determine if the form justifies anti-forgery, and if it doesn't, suppress anti-forgery on the target action. Cacing and anti-forgery can't be reconciled: the very purpose of anti-forgery is to make sure of the origin of a post. If you can just copy an old post with its token, that defies the purpose, so the token is time-sensitive.

Comment: So, as I read it on your blog (http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/opting-out-of-anti-forgery-validation-in-orchard) anti-forgery suppression can be done by that attribute. Is it safe to merge this part of code into the 1.8 codebase? On the other hand, in order to disable cache for a certain page: did you mean  by using the OutputCache attribute on the controller action? And one more thing: would you please respond as an answer, so I could mark it as an asnwer :) Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes, that changeset should be fine to merge, but I'd suggest taking 1.9 instead. I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have both anti-forgery and caching, on the same form, because the anti-forgery token is not reusable and is part of the response. As a consequence, you need to choose between them. Any form that has information that shouldn't be possible to forge (and that's almost any form) should have anti-forgery on. So the default solution should be to disable caching, using the `[OutputCache]` attribute on the controller action that renders the form. If you prefer caching over anti-forgery, anti-forgery can now be turned off action by action, using the `[ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOrchard]` attribute on the action that is the target of the form.
But again, disabling caching should be preferred.